# How Can I Implement Isotope Filtering with URL Hashes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

(Though this mentions Wordpress throughout, I don't think this is a Wordpress specific problem)

I am working on a personal website using Wordpress and one of the packages that the theme uses is [Isotope by Metafizzy](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/). This is for filtering posts on the page with links.

You can see the page [here](http://thedivtagguy.com)

I wanted to try implementing something similar to [mypoorbrain.com](http://mypoorbrain.com) where the page is filtered with URL hashes. The advantage of this is that if the user is one another page, he can navigate to `http://www.mypoorbrain.com/#illustration` and still end up on the filtered content.

I went through the Isotope docs and there [is a section for implementing URL hashes](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#url-hash) and this is the code I'm inserting before the closing `<head>` tag:

```html
<script>
  function getHashFilter() {
    var hash = location.hash;
    // get filter=filterName
    var matches = location.hash.match(/filter=([^&]+)/i);
    var hashFilter = matches && matches[1];
    return hashFilter && decodeURIComponent(hashFilter);
  }
  $(function() {

    var $grid = $('.isotope');

    // bind filter button click
    var $filters = $('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
      var filterAttr = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      // set filter in hash
      location.hash = 'filter=' + encodeURIComponent(filterAttr);
    });

    var isIsotopeInit = false;

    function onHashchange() {
      var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
      if (!hashFilter && isIsotopeInit) {
        return;
      }
      isIsotopeInit = true;
      // filter isotope
      $grid.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.selector col-md-6 col-lg-4',
        filter: hashFilter
      });
      // set selected class on button
      if (hashFilter) {
        $filters.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $filters.find('[data-filter="' + hashFilter + '"]').addClass('is-checked');
      }
    }

    $(window).on('hashchange', onHashchange);
    // trigger event handler to init Isotope
    onHashchange();
  });
</script>
```

But this does nothing.

I think the issue here is with correctly selecting the div elements (both links and the elements being sorted). From what I could guess using inspect element, the code for selecting the entire items grid is `.selector col-md-6 col-lg-4'`, and the code for finding the filter buttons(or links) is `var $filterButtonGroup = $('.m-filters');`  but like I said, this does nothing.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that the filters appear as hash links in the address bar?

Comment: I don't know if you heard something about mixitup library but it is a super easy filtering method which worked in my case

Comment: @ProKemikon I've just had a look at it. Does it support URL hashes? The reason I'm sticking to Isotope is that it's built into my theme. :/

Comment: Can you show a working demo of what you've tried? (codepan, jsbin..)

Comment: @MoshFeu I've tried, rather badly, to load what was possible in a codepen file [here](https://codepen.io/thedivtagguy/pen/jOrVWRx), but the filtering process does not work. The working demo, what my understanding is, is on the website I've linked in the post ( [this one](http://thedivtagguy.com) ). I'll update my post to reflect the code I've tried most recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps to the solution:

1. There is no element with the class `.isotope`, so add this class to the parent (the `.row` element).
2. The inline `style` you set to the children conflicts with the style isotope suppose to set, remove it.
3. You listen to `click` events on the `a` elements while the `data-filter` is on the `li`s. So change the event listener to `$('#filters').on( 'click', 'li',..` (You can also bind the `click` event in a different way but it's out of this answer's scope).
4. You don't need the `itemSelector` option (when you call to `$grid.isotope`) since you want to filter the direct children which is the default behaviour. BTW, `.selector col-md-6 col-lg-4'` is invalid selector. If any, it should be `.selector.col-md-6.col-lg-4'`.

I gather all these changes in the following commit: https://github.com/moshfeu/isotope.js/commit/62b9798871e9452ade26d6e2863699869b8cb612.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I've referred to the code back and forth with the points you've mentioned and it makes sense what I was doing wrong! If you don't mind helping me just a bit further, I've added the JS code from the compiled commit on my page with a `<script>`, however when I go to the page using [a url hash](https://thedivtagguy.com/#mishmash), the isotope grid is still stuck at `All`. Was there supposed to be some other way to add it in?

Comment: Copy paste from github diff is risky ;). For example, there left `@@ -27,15 +26,17 @@ $( function() {`. Try to copy only the newer version - https://github.com/moshfeu/isotope.js/blob/62b9798871e9452ade26d6e2863699869b8cb612/index.js.

Comment: No luck, do try the link! https://thedivtagguy.com/#mishmash 

I did notice that on line 32 `// itemSelector: '.selector.col-md-6.col-lg-4',` has been commented out. Would removing that make a difference?

Comment: It should be commented. By some reason, your jQuery version used `jQuery` but not exposing the `$` function. So you can wrap the code with `(($) => {
  // the code goes here
})(jQuery);`. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3ZJa.png

Comment: Nvm, I've tried it on another page and it works like a charm! Thank you so much. One last question if I can bother you with as much, is it possible to remove `#filter=.mishmash` and have it just be `#mishmash`? Because currently it doesn't work if I don't type that in.

Comment: It can be if you'd replace `var matches = location.hash.match( /filter=([^&]+)/i );` to just `location.hash` and the filter links to `location.hash = 'encodeURIComponent( filterAttr );`